# Serialize complex dictionary with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, datacontractjsonserializer

With .NET 4.5 version of *DataContractJsonSerializer* and with help of *DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat* I can serialize dictionaries. So for example this dictionary:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object> 
{
  { "Level", 3 },
  { "Location", "Catacomb" }
};
```

will be converted into nice JSON:

```
{
  "Level":3,
  "Location":"Catacomb"
}
```

But if I have another dictionary as value:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object> 
{
    { "Level", 3 },
    { "Location", new Dictionary<string, object> 
        {
            { "Name", "Catacobms" }
        }
    }
};
```

the the resulted JSON looks really bad:

```
{
   "Level":3,
   "Location":[
      {
         "__type":"KeyValuePairOfstringanyType:#System.Collections.Generic",
         "key":"Name",
         "value":"Catacobms"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?

PS: I know that there are other good JSON serializers, but in this case I need to use *DataContractJsonSerializer*.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `EmitTypeInformation` property on the serializer to `EmitTypeInformation.Never`

See [MSDN Entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.emittypeinformation.aspx)